# CPU load too high after upgrade from 1.8 to 11.23.1

Tags: linux, asterisk, cpu-usage

Feel free to shoot me down in case there is more data that i can provide. I have gone through some blogs on serverfault and other blogs and gathered as much info as I can.

I want to track/fix cause of high cpu load. As call on this server almost double in next 6 months

CPU load has been quite high since we upgraded system.

This is bare metal setup, no virtulization:
8 cores
32 G Ram
handles 600+ calls during peak time
Load average can go up to 50's
noticing this ONLY since upgraded from Asterisk `1.8` to `11.23.1`
Linux version - Linux version `3.16.0-4-amd64` (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org)

Another machine using Asterisk 1.8 with similar load does not have similar high load issue.

Below are some output:

```
top - 12:52:25 up 487 days, 15:12, 4 users, load average: 49.90, 28.53, 20.71
Tasks: 192 total, 1 running, 191 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 14.1 us, 11.0 sy, 0.1 ni, 72.0 id, 0.6 wa, 0.0 hi, 2.1 si, 0.0 st
KiB Mem: 32774572 total, 31901268 used, 873304 free, 233072 buffers
KiB Swap: 15624188 total, 27732 used, 15596456 free. 28175700 cached Mem

PID USER PR NI VIRT RES SHR S %CPU %MEM TIME+ COMMAND
73940 asterisk 20 0 6520900 1.524g 19264 S 198.4 4.9 574:50.48 asterisk
84532 root 20 0 490524 234432 14120 S 2.0 0.7 538:14.15 captagent
73955 root 20 0 56912 11300 3040 S 1.7 0.0 13:57.47 mysql-proxy
25 root 20 0 0 0 0 S 1.0 0.0 73:40.51 ksoftirqd/3
3 root 20 0 0 0 0 S 0.3 0.0 1662:43 ksoftirqd/0
8 root 20 0 0 0 0 S 0.3 0.0 1115:01 rcu_sched
5674 root 20 0 23636 2828 2296 S 0.3 0.0 10:04.49 top
```

---

```
top - 11:27:42 up 487 days, 13:47, 4 users, load average: 40.79, 34.43, 31.62
Tasks: 189 total, 1 running, 188 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie
%Cpu0 : 9.7 us, 8.7 sy, 0.0 ni, 75.0 id, 0.7 wa, 0.0 hi, 6.0 si, 0.0 st
%Cpu1 : 16.0 us, 14.3 sy, 12.9 ni, 54.7 id, 0.7 wa, 0.0 hi, 1.4 si, 0.0 st
%Cpu2 : 11.5 us, 9.8 sy, 0.3 ni, 75.7 id, 0.0 wa, 0.0 hi, 2.7 si, 0.0 st
%Cpu3 : 20.1 us, 15.0 sy, 0.0 ni, 55.1 id, 0.7 wa, 0.0 hi, 9.1 si, 0.0 st
%Cpu4 : 9.3 us, 10.3 sy, 0.0 ni, 80.1 id, 0.0 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.3 si, 0.0 st
%Cpu5 : 21.3 us, 16.0 sy, 0.0 ni, 62.3 id, 0.3 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.0 si, 0.0 st
%Cpu6 : 7.1 us, 9.1 sy, 0.0 ni, 83.4 id, 0.3 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.0 si, 0.0 st
%Cpu7 : 18.1 us, 15.4 sy, 0.0 ni, 66.2 id, 0.3 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.0 si, 0.0 st
KiB Mem: 32774572 total, 31925508 used, 849064 free, 232344 buffers
KiB Swap: 15624188 total, 26352 used, 15597836 free. 28303972 cached Mem

PID USER PR NI VIRT RES SHR S %CPU %MEM TIME+ COMMAND
73940 asterisk 20 0 6463216 1.427g 19264 S 210.1 4.6 382:14.33 asterisk
73955 root 20 0 55400 9716 3040 S 1.7 0.0 12:11.70 mysql-proxy
84532 root 20 0 490524 233396 14120 S 1.7 0.7 536:42.82 captagent
25 root 20 0 0 0 0 S 1.0 0.0 73:02.67 ksoftirqd/3

/proc/interrupts

110: 1669403939 252693 0 0 0 0 0 0 PCI-MSI-edge eth0-tx-0
111: 4070210232 466049458 128053 0 0 0 0 0 PCI-MSI-edge eth0-rx-1
112: 3977477299 0 256234622 47225 0 0 0 0 PCI-MSI-edge eth0-rx-2
113: 2078000933 295945 0 1528295501 0 0 0 0 PCI-MSI-edge eth0-rx-3
```

What I am planning to grab here is to break down where resources are going "with in Asterisk". At least then I have direction or point to compare.

- Is there break down on where Asterisk is consuming more resources?
- Is this in codec conversions?
- Is it in call setup is it running out of IO?

Comment: there's 2 sip servers in asterisk 11, do you know which one is registered with users?  chan_sip or pjsip

Comment: any errors in `asterisk -rv`

Comment: Chan_sip and no errors in asterisk -rv, all calls and everything goes fine.

Answer (score 0):

Biggest consumer of CPU is transcoding.  When you recreated peers/users did you force the right codecs & order?  If not your box might be doing some transcoding.  Check transcoding when calls are up.

Comment: This may sound like stupid question. How do i check transcoding ?

Comment: Answered my own question : asterisk -rx 'core show translation'